# How does Math.ceil(double) work?

Tags: java

I came up with a problem while using Math.ceil() method. Shouldn't it give the closest integer bigger than the parameter if we typecast the result to integer? For the specific value (int)Math.ceil(1/5) gives 0 as a result. How should I use it to get 1 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/5 using integer math produces 0. You need to use floating point math to get 0.2 so that `ceil` has something to round up.

```
(int) Math.ceil(1.0/5.0)
```